# Haskell - list product

Tags: haskell

I know this question has been asked before. I worked through various posts but can't seem to find a solution to the problem. I have a simple Haskell program that creates a list of values. I then want to either call Prelude's product function, or my own. Either, way, each time I call these functions on my list-generating function, I get a zero result. When I sum the values in the list, the are added correctly, which makes me think that perhaps the multiplication function is using the list before it is instantiated. The code lookes something like this:

```
module Main where

...

sumVals::[Int]->Int
sumVals = foldr (+) 0

multVals::[Int]->Int
--multVals  list = foldl (*) 1 list
multVals [] = 1
multVals (x:xs) = x * multVals xs

...

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    ...
    print $ sumVals (listCreator num) -- prints correct sum value
    print $ sum (listCreator num) -- prints correct sum value
    print $ multVals (listCreator num) -- prints: 0
    print $ product (listCreator num) -- prints: 0
    print $ foldl (*) 1 (listCreator num) -- prints: 0
    print $ product [1,1,3,1] -- prints: 3
    let list = fib num
    print $ multVals list -- prints: 0
    print $ product list -- prints: 0
```

Comment: What does `listCreator` do? If its creations have any 0s, that would explain things.

Comment: When using `Int`, multiplying enough 2's (or multiples) will eventually get 0. Try `Integer` instead.

Comment: @chi, I didn't even notice that these were `Int`s. Nice catch.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `listCreator` does or what `num` is, but it appears that `listCreator num` is a list that contains 0.

As chi mentioned in a comment, another possibility is integer overflow. You can rule this out by switching to the `Integer` type.